# Using a project's package in another project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

how can I use the classes of a package out of the main project where it has been defined?
for example imagine there is an Employee class in package people which belongs to ProjectOne. let's assume Employee is needed in another project (ProjectTwo) with the same features.What should I do there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on ProjectTwo in the Package Explorer. Go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path. Go to the Projects tab, click Add, select ProjectOne, and click OK, then click OK again to exit the project properties window.

Then import your classes as usual - within ProjectTwo, you should be able to see ProjectOne's classes as if they were in the same project.

Comment: Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since i dont know wich eclipse your using i tryed this on eclipse kelpler

you can Drag packages into  the other Projects  src folder to use them