# importing a package from another project into the current project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I,m currently onto a project by name **'days_display'** which basically displays the name of the day of a current date.(one of the features)
I need to import an enum **'days_of_week'** that holds the values of all the days of the week from my previous project **'enum_works'** which has the source folder **'src'** and **default package** inside which is the required enum i.e **'days_of_week'**.(in **eclipse**)

when i say **'import enum_works.days_of_week;'** it gives me an error saying that enum_works cannot be resolved.
I also tried **'import enum_works.default_package;'** and **'import enum-works.*;'.**
But I get the same error.

I included the project **'enum-work'** into my build path too. but no go.

How do i import an external enum into my current project?

Comment: Is this not working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472104/using-a-projects-package-in-another-project-in-eclipse

Comment: I tried to do that too..  but dint work

Comment: You never prefix a java class name with a *project name*. You can only import a class from the package in which it was defined. A class defined in the default (unnamed) package cannot be imported. The solution is to put your days_of_week enum inside a package, then make your project available as a dependency of another project, and then import that package in which you declared your days_of_week enum

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt how do i make a project available to another project as a dependency in eclipse? i searched the whole ide but no go..looked up the net to find it is  a feature in maven with eclipse!

Comment: @codepoetly That's what in Arun's link - read it carefully. Managing the build path is considered very basic stuff in Eclipse / Java.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt  yeah that worked... thanks.... earlier i tried to add only the required individual classes in the build path.. is that why it dint work?